# XSLT - 'a href' within an element that is not part of atribute

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So i have this piece of an XML document I'm working on in class.

```
<etymology>The <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakama">Yakama</a> Native American tribe</etymology>
```

it contains a href within the element of Etymology. When the XSLT transforms this by default, the link gets 'deactivated' in a way that only the text shows and it no longer links out to another page.

I need to know what to do here:

```
<td width="25%">
    <xsl:value-of select="etymology"/>
</td>
```

So that the links as many as there may be in the Etymology element will translate or appear as a link and not transform into plain text.

My current and ONLY template defined in the stylesheet is this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Washington Counties</title>          
        </head>

        <body>
        <h1>Washington Counties</h1>
        <p>
            ( <a><xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="counties/@source" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            data source</a> )
        </p>

        <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

            <tr><th>County</th><th>INCITS</th><th>County Seat</th><th>Established</th><th>Origin</th><th>Etymology</th><th>Population</th><th>Area</th><th>Map</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="counties/county">
                <xsl:sort select="established" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Grays Harbor County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#b">b</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Mason County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#c">c</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Kitsap County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#d">d</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Clark County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#e">e</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Yakima County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#f">f</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Jefferson County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#g">g</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="name = 'Clallam County'" >
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
                            </a> 
                             <sup><a href="#g">g</a></sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            </a>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="incits/@href" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="incits" /></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="countySeat/@href" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="countySeat" /></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="established = 1879">    
                            <xsl:value-of select="established" /> <sup>
                                <a href="#a">a</a>
                            </sup>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="established" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="origin != 0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="origin" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        Original County
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td width="25%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="etymology"/>
                </td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="population" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="area[@unit='mi2']" /> sq mi
                <br />(<xsl:value-of select="area[@unit='km2']" /> sq km)
                </td>
                <td>
                <img>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="map/@src" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./name" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </table>

        <br />
        <strong>Footnotes</strong>
        <br />
        <xsl:for-each select="counties/footnote">
            <p>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />. <xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </body>     
    </html> 
</xsl:template>
```

and lastly the XML file I am transforming:
http://puu.sh/n4XiV.xml

Comment: This is a good example why you need to post a [mcve] rather than snippets taken out of context.

Comment: Please post your XML inside your question (preferably minimized).

Comment: I cannot post the XML file because it is over the 30000 character limit.

Comment: You obviously did not read the link above. Specifically, the part that says "*Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem*".

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:value-of` will, as the name says, only take the value of the node. You need to use `xsl:apply-templates` for the processor to continue processing the contents as they are.

Since the default action is to copy, you will get everything inside the tag in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="etymology"/>
```

do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="etymology/node()"/>
```

and make sure you have a templates that copy `a` and text nodes.

Comment: By templates, do you mean i have to make a new <xsl:template match=""> in where match will contain something in relation to 'a'? And, something similar for the text within the reference link?

Comment: @Invert_Tails I cannot answer your question without knowing what other templates you already have. That's what my comment to your question is about.

Comment: I have updated my question with the files and template related to the snippets, i hope this helps.